# How can I test which mains wire belongs to neutral and which to ground?

Tags: ground, grounding

I currently live in Spain, in an old building, where apparently electrical codes don't strictly apply... because not all outlets have ground or, indeed, not all connections are grounded. To make matters worse, the colours on the wires used are, well, haphazard, to say the least...

So if I want to install my own grounded outlets to avoid "exploding" my electrical stuff (because there're constant surges that have already fried 2 computer transformers) and in the wall I see mains wires of lovely rainbow colours that don't really tell me which is which, **how can I test which wire belongs to neutral and which wire belongs to ground?**

Comment: Probably not the best answer, but if your building at least has a GFCI/RCD you could test which way around causes that to trip; a resistor between live and neutral won't trip it, but one between live and ground will.

Comment: That's clever but does that assume you know which wire is gnd?  I would use the plumbing as a reference voltage .

Comment: Do you know what style of 'ground' your building thinks it uses? This might affect the potential fault scenarios, and possibly narrow down how much the difference matters. Do you have a 2-pole incomer isolator?

Comment: With a home in an area that has spikes or surges the best method would be to add a whole house surge suppressor at the service panel, by installing at the service panel everything in the home is protected.

Comment: Employ an electrician If you don't know what you are doing it could kill you.  This sounds like a cop out but it is not worth the risk.

Comment: Grounded outlets will not help with issues caused by voltage spikes, you need to install surge suppressors. The power supplies in computers don't really care which side is live relative to ground, both are treated as live.

Comment: buy a cheap outlet tester, it will tell you what's going on in a foolproof and safe manner.